# C# Assert at compile time Func argument is static

Tags: c#, compilation

Is there any way at compile time to assert an argument Func is static?

This seems like something the compiler could easily check rather than relying on runtime failure.

I realise it can be done at runtime with [arg].Method.IsStatic

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems like something the compiler could easily check rather than relying on runtime failure.

Yes, it absolutely could - but only if there's something in the language to prompt it to do so. There isn't, in C# - it's a pretty odd requirement, IMO, and one which doesn't play nicely with lambda expressions.

With VS 2015 you could easily write a Roslyn CodeDiagnostic to spot this and throw up a warning or error. You'd probably want to decorate the parameter with an attribute for the diagnostic to spot, and then check all callers.

Comment: The argument function handles a transaction with a database which can fail if another process is concurrently attempting to manipulate the data.

I'm writing a wrapper to allow it to attempt multiple times before failing. I'd like to enforce the argument function has no external effect if it fails.

Comment: @user2036256: Well requiring it to be a static method is neither sufficient nor required for that to be the case...

Comment: I'm aware. But its a step in the right direction. Its more as a friendly reminder. In an ideal world the classes calling through to this would also be static but we need inheritance.

This would at least enforce the methods in the class are.

Comment: @user2036256: Hmm.. not sure I'd personally call it a step in the right direction, but anyway, a Roslyn CodeDiagnostic does sound like what you want. Of course, that means using Visual Studio 2015, which isn't released yet - so you may need to make do with a runtime check for the moment, and build the diagnostic later...